# Installing Homebrew on Macbook running El Capitan

Tags: ruby, installation, homebrew

When I run this command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I get the following error:

```
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
The current contents of /usr/local are bin CODEOFCONDUCT.md git include lib libexec Library LICENSE.txt n share var .git .github .gitignore
```

However, when I run `brew doctor`, this error is thrown:

```
bash: brew: command not found
```

And when I try to un-install Homebrew using this script:

```
sudo  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

my command prompt responds with:

```
Failed to locate Homebrew!
```

Please help.

Comment: does it returns anything if you run `ls /usr/local/bin | grep brew`?

Comment: Also what does it says when you run `which ruby`?

Comment: @RogérioPeixoto Terminal returns `brew.rb` when I run the first command and `/usr/bin/ruby` when I run the second command.

Answer (score 2):

First delete all homebrew files manually. Then reinstall Homebrew from scratch. Prefix `sudo` at your own discretion:

```
# packages
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar

# executable
rm /usr/local/bin/brew

# meta
rm -rf /usr/local/.git
rm /usr/local/.github
rm /usr/local/.gitignore
rm /usr/local/.travis.yml
rm /usr/local/.yardopts
rm /usr/local/CODEOFCONDUCT.md
rm /usr/local/LICENSE.txt
rm /usr/local/README.md

# home
rm ~/.rvm/bin/brew
rm ~/.homebrew
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew

# other
rm -rf /Library/Caches/Homebrew

# find more files to delete; delete Homebrew files only!
find / -name "*brew*"
```

**IMPORTANT:** because of permission errors upon reinstall, you may have to do one of the following steps before reinstallation; see: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/15138

```
# via: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/15138#issuecomment-19258042
cd /usr/local
sudo mv -v Library Library.old

# --OR--

# via: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/15138#issuecomment-33338868
# see: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chmod1.html
cd /usr/local
chmod -R 775 Library
```

Reinstall Homebrew; see: http://brew.sh

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: This answer also didn't work, for the same reason as the other answer. I uninstalled Homebrew, and then ran the command to reinstall Homebrew. It gave me a fatal error during `git reset --hard origin/master`. When I tried to install Homebrew again, my terminal replied with `It appears Homebrew is already installed`.

Comment: @JeremyHadfield My bad, I just noticed an error in my solution and fixed it. `rm /usr/local/.git` is now `rm -rf /usr/local/.git` because `.git` is a directory.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem. I still got this error: `fatal: cannot unlink 'Library/Aliases/0mq': Permission denied
Failed during: git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: @JeremyHadfield I updated the answer to include a solution for the permission errors you're experiencing with the reinstall.

Comment: If you're getting permission error try prefixing with sudo as @SoAwesomeMan suggested

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem related to the latest version of XCode and Homebrew. Open a terminal and run:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

If you get permission denied error use `sudo`. Directory `/usr/local/Cellar/` is completely removed when uninstalling Homebrew, so it is safe to remove it.

Comment: This didn't work. When I ran the second command, I got this error: 

`fatal: cannot unlink 'Library/Aliases/0mq': Permission denied
Failed during: git reset --hard origin/master`

When I tried to run it with sudo, it told me 

`Don't run this as root!`

Comment: I guess it might be ownership problem. Try `chown -R $USER` on the `Library` in `/usr/local/`. And then try to `curl` again.